# activate/deactivate plugin option for particular file type in Intellij plugin development

Tags: java, plugins, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am developing a plugin for Intellij, which has number of actions.

I want to disable some actions by default, and they would get activated only for certain file types.

e.g. When I right click on .java file it should be deactivated or disabled.  However, when I right click on an .xml file, then that particular plugin action should be activated or enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class YourAction extends DumbAwareAction {
    ...
    @Override
    public void update(AnActionEvent e) {
        super.update(e);
        determineVisibility(e);
    }

    private void determineVisibility(AnActionEvent e) {
        DataContext dataContext = e.getDataContext();
        VirtualFile virtualFile = PlatformDataKeys.VIRTUAL_FILE.getData(dataContext);
        e.getPresentation().setVisible(isXml(virtualFile));
    }

    private boolean isXml(VirtualFile file) {
        if (file == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return XmlFileType.INSTANCE.equals(file.getFileType());
    }
}
```